# ¿Se usa? : No pensar + imperfecto subjuntivo

Tags: subjuntivo, tiempos-pasados

En las dos aplicaciones que uso (SpanishDict, Google Translate), la oración inglesa “I don’t think that you were at the party yesterday” se traduce a “no pienso que estuvieras en la fiesta ayer.” También, me parece que esta frase coincide con la regla del subjuntivo “opiniones actuales de eventos en el pasado.” Ejemplos de SpanishDict abajo:

> Es bueno que él se casara/casase. (It's good that he got married.)
>
> No me parece que el viaje fuera/fuese largo. (It doesn't seem to me that the journey was long.)

Lo que pasa es que hoy mi profesor actual me dijo que “No creo que estuvieras en la fiesta ayer” es equivocado, y la única manera correcta decir esa es “No creo que hubieras estado en la fiesta ayer.” Él repasó el ejemplo con otros profesores en la escuela, y le dijeron lo mismo. (Si importa, mi escuela es en Oaxaca, México.)

Mi pregunta es, ¿se puede usar oraciones que usan “No pienso/no creo/dudo que” + el subjuntivo imperfecto, como en mi ejemplo? ¿O mi profesor es correcto y hay que usar “hubiera” + pasado participio? (Pienso que ese tiempo se llama “El pluscuamperfecto de subjuntivo.”)

Answer (score 2):

No sé cómo es en el español de Mexico, pero en España tus profesores no tendrían razón.  La forma en la que yo lo diría es:

- No creo que hayas estado en la fiesta

o

- No creo que estuvieras a la fiesta.

La razón es que, en indicativo, la frase sería "No estabas en la fiesta" (pretérito imperfecto) o "No has estado en la fiesta" (pretérito perfecto compuesto), y lo normal es usar el mismo tiempo en la forma subjuntiva. La frase en pretérito pluscuamperfecto de indicativo no tiene sentido en este contexto ("No habías estado en la fiesta"), por lo que "no creo que hubieras estado..." tampoco tendría sentido para mí.

El uso del pretérito pluscuamperfecto de subjuntivo solo tendría sentido si el contexto lo requiere, como por ejemplo en un condicional incierto o si se están comparando dos instantes en el tiempo:

- Si tuvieras un examen al día siguiente, no creo que hubieras estado en la fiesta.
- Cuando llegué a casa te vi en pijama, así que no pensé que hubieras estado en la fiesta.

Answer (score 1):

El pretérito imperfecto de subjuntivo aparece habitualmente en oraciones temporales y adjetivas, **sustituyendo al pretérito pluscuamperfecto de indicativo** (*había sido*) **y al pretérito perfecto simple** (*fue*).

Entre las amplias características que tiene el subjuntivo, el uso del pretérito imperfecto de subjuntivo incluye también la de **la percepción subjetiva**, poniendo de manifiesto la actitud o percepción del hablante ante la información que expone de forma que la verdad o falsedad del enunciado se encuentre en un segundo plano.

La oración que precede al verbo en subjuntivo indica que se trata de una **percepción subjetiva** del hablante ante una determinada información.

- No creo que ayer **estuvieras** en la fiesta. (*Apreciación subjetiva*)

---

Dentro de los diferentes tipos de **percepciones subjetivas** tenemos;

- Emociones y sentimientos.
- Deseos y Voluntades.
- Consejos, recomendaciones, órdenes y peticiones.
- Valoraciones.
- **Opiniones negadas y dudas.**
- Probabilidad e hipótesis.

---

**Opiniones negadas y dudas**

**Los verbos de opinión y de pensamiento van seguidos de subjuntivo solo cuando la oración principal está negada**.

Verbos de opinión - *creer, estar seguro de, parecer, pensar, suponer, etc*.

**Excepción** - El verbo **dudar** va seguido siempre de subjuntivo.

**Ejemplos**

- Ya no dudaba que **fuera** más productiva desde casa.
- No creo que **echara** de menos la ciudad.
- No creo que me **cansara** de la vida en el campo.
- No creo que ayer **estuvieras** en la fiesta.

---

Por tanto, decir;

- No creo que ayer **estuvieras** en la fiesta.
- No pienso que ayer **estuvieras** en la fiesta.

"**Es Correcto**".